# Conditional column type in GridView

Tags: gridview

I'm using ASP.NET GridView control in one of my projects. In one of the columns I'm getting values which I want to use to define the type of the cell. For example, if the cell contains a value equal to "ABC", I want to show "ABC" as a hyperlink and as an ordinary text if it is not equal to "ABC". Could anybody help me with a clue on how can this be done?

Thanks in advance.